# Keep getting FormatException on DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am trying to convert a date stored as string to DateTime using `DateTime.ParseExact` like below

```
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("3/14/2023 4:08:30 PM", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null);
```

but I keep getting a `FormatException`error on that line.

I have tried tweaking the format, but nothing works. What am I missing here?

Comment: What culture are you in? Different cultures have different date and time separators. I suggest you use the invariant culture if possible, *or* quote the separators. (The culture can also affect the AM/PM designators.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Great, using invariant culture worked! Thanks and please post this as an answer so I can accept it. PS: I am a big fan of your work, and have your book on C#. An honor to have you help me, really haha

Comment: "An honor to have you help me" - and yet you completely ignored what @JonSkeet asked - the question was (and still is) missing the information on "What culture are you in"... (Obviously the real answer is to use culture that matches the data or ISO8601 format - Jon's suggestion is just to get you unblocked - but he would definitely provide that in the real answer if he decides to post one).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov true, forgot to answer him. My culture is PT-BR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code uses the default culture from the currently-executing thread. Even though you've specified a custom date/time format string, the culture can still affect it:

- It affects how numbers are parsed (as not every culture uses '0'-'9')
- It affects which calendar system the value is interpreted in
- It affects the date separators (between year, month and day)
- It affects the time separators (between hour, month and minute)
- It affects the strings used for AM and PM

Unless the text has come from a user, it's usually best to explicitly specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the culture to parse in - at which point you know (or *can* know) exactly what will be used for each of the variations above.